# Python Selenium querying page elements without driver.refresh()

Tags: python, selenium

Without using `Driver.refresh()` can I see if an item has changed from out of stock to in stock? After reading some of the other posts I could just query the page elements again?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.list-wrap div.item-container')))

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.list-wrap div.item-container')

stock = elements.find_element_by_css_selector('p.item-promo').text
```

Comment: As there is no website provided, to know the usecase, it is hard to answer. But in general you could say, that if the elements change without refreshing your page in the browser, it should be possible to query them again and get their updated status

Comment: @NationBoneless www.Newegg.com would it work on this website?

Comment: I don't know this page, but from what I can see, there are no live updates. This would be an Example [UTC TIME](https://time.is/UTC) , as the time keeps changing. It seems to me like you want to regularly call a website to check whether something is in stock now. That would be more managable through the refresh I believe